# Why does the property of an object used in the union has the type any?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, union-types

I have a component that has 3 props: `toValue`, `fromValue`, `children`. The first 2 of them are optional, but if one of them is specified, then the other must also be specified. The `children` prop is a function that has the `inputProps` argument, which should be equal to either the return type of `toValue` function (`TInputValue`), if specified, or `TStateValue`.

I wrote the following code, but I didn't understand why `inputProps` is `any` in cases where the `toValue` function is specified. How to fix it?

```
interface IP<T> {
  value: T
  onChange: (value: T) => void
}
interface A<TStateValue> {
  toValue?: never
  fromValue?: never
  children: (inputProps: IP<TStateValue>) => null
}
interface B<TStateValue, TInputValue>  {
  toValue: (value: TStateValue) => TInputValue
  fromValue: (value: TInputValue) => TStateValue
  children: (inputProps: IP<TInputValue>) => null
}
type C<TStateValue, TInputValue> =
  | A<TStateValue>
  | B<TStateValue, TInputValue>

const propsWithoutToValue: C<number, string> = {
  children: (inputProps) => null, // `inputProps` is `IP<number>`. Nice!
}
const propsWithToValue: C<number, string> = {
  toValue: (value) => value.toString(), // The return type is a `string`, so the `inputProps` must be `IP<string>`
  fromValue: (value) => Number(value),
  children: (inputProps) => null, // `inputProps` is any, but must be `IP<string>`. How to fix it?
}
```

I have created a repo with my problem that I'm trying to solve: https://github.com/oxilor/form-types

Answer (score 2, accepted):

quick solution:

```
interface IP<T> {
  value: T
  onChange: (value: T) => void
}
interface A<TStateValue> {
  type:"A",
  children(inputProps: IP<TStateValue>, a:1) : null
}
interface B<TStateValue, TInputValue>  {
  type: "B",
  toValue: (value: TStateValue) => TInputValue
  fromValue: (value: TInputValue) => TStateValue
  children(inputProps: IP<TInputValue>) : null
}

type C<TStateValue, TInputValue> =
  | B<TStateValue, TInputValue>
  | A<TStateValue>

const propsWithoutToValue: C<number, string> = {
  type: "A",
  children: (inputProps) => null,
  //          ^?
}
const propsWithToValue: C<number, string> = {
  type: "B",
  toValue: (value) => value.toString(), 
  fromValue: (value) => Number(value),
  children: (inputProps) => null,
  //            ^?
}
```

[image]

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIAUA8AVAfMgbwChlkA3OAGwFcIAuZbE5AexAGEALOEAc3uQAKCjQHYAlMgC8+Mi2AATIgF8ioSLEQoAgjgDKYOJABqVWvmKkwATwAO9AETaHAGmYJOwSgqgQQg0FtqMHQoFlsAZwYMfUMTMwhcF2Q4OgBGSQYQakpKFTVwaHgkZAAhWKMIU1Fk7FQQILBq81JLZBt7BgdS12YwFmaBYQSGbANKwckZRnrGweYYMIBbQYZh0VHZ4MnpfDG4qoT3T29ff0Dg0PCotCw6hu2E3EzkbNz8og6Udgr4mpmHk0ntJmAAfMq-Q7-e5zJ5g5C6fYTOFEBBsCJgZC2MKRADqwDAnBYwWwAxGyB+2SWACNoMkMVBQLx8FJCH07AInL1SB4vD4-GsLiEcREpvg3pQ3KQAPTS0jyhXIAB6AH58miQBisSL8YTSasKZgqbSoPSwIy+Cy2VYOV0elL2mSNkIRLQxeQEgA6foGC28QTiZILZYG9Zu3bIABy1Bp0DDEEDxz5Z0FgKukXdEodssVueVauUQA)

//========================observation===========

point A: if you try to union 2 function with different argument type, the argument type is `any`

[image]

**important update: [why function "union" parameter appear as `any` but is actually `never` or something else](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74844452/5338829)**

point B: the reason typescript think you try to union 2 functions is because union function with the same object properties behave in the same way as union of both functions

[image]

this basically mean `{b:((a:1)=>void)} | {b:((a:number)=>void)}` is literally `{b:((a:1)=>void) | ((a:number)=>void)}`

there are few things that I cant explain:

1. the justification behind behavior shown in point A and B (what is the purpose)
2. it seem like discriminated union (or union in general) not working properly with function type (or not working instinctively)
3. point A does not apply to propsWithoutToValue but apply to propsWithToValue, most likely is the after effect of point 2

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative approach using [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html).

We have two generic types at play here.  There is the type which determines the props provided to the `children` function.  I am calling this `TChildProps` and I am putting this first because it is always present.

Then there is the type `TStateValue` which is only relevant in situation `B`.

In situation `A`, your state can be provided directly to the `children` function and therefore it doesn't require `toValue` and `fromValue` converter functions.

**The conditional says that if the state can be passed directly to the `children` (`TStateValue extends TChildProps`) then we are in situation `A`.  If the state is a different type, then we are in situation `B` and must provide converters.**

```
type C<TChildProps, TStateValue = TChildProps> =
  TStateValue extends TChildProps ? A<TStateValue> : B<TStateValue, TChildProps>
```

---

The generics on `C` are little bit different than what you had before.

In the case of `propsWithoutToValue`, we only need the `number` type.

```
const propsWithoutToValue: C<number> = {
  children: (inputProps) => null, // `inputProps` is `IP<number>`. Nice!
}
```

In the case of `propsWithToValue`, the order of the two generics is now reversed.

```
const propsWithToValue: C<string, number> = {
  toValue: (value) => value.toString(),
  fromValue: (value) => Number(value),
  children: (inputProps) => null, // `inputProps` is `IP<string>`.  We did it!
}
```

The first generic type parameter `string` will make the `inputProps` have type `IP<string>`.

As the second generic type parameter `number` is not assignable to `string`, we must provide a `toValue` function that converts `number` to `string` and a `fromValue` function that converts `string` to `number`.

[TypeScript Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIAUA8AVAfMgbwFgAoZZANzgBsBXCALmW1PIHsQBhACzhAHNGyABRU6Q7AEpkAXnwU2wACakAvqVKhIsRCgCCOAMpg4kAGo16%20YmWRg2F8QH4mICBWitkMKGwC2jvQuyG4eUF4I3MDUSlAQIEzCoAAOtGDovskAzkwYRibmlhC40nIhtNTUahokWtDwSMgAQvmmEIEQADTMqCCpYB34hF72HYli9EzYxm0dpfjYvf0dXj7%20YyITEktpc7ILM4XiEVExcQkiKWkZbNm5WIt9u0Ul%20%20WV1SSkYACeySicHA8aJKG7ZbrTArtIqyZjAmJgrL4GTMQ7Q8TICAAD0gICUWThp1BmQJTmQBkhsxeyCYLUpR3oEPhxNuSJqCA4WTAyGSJIA6sAwNw2GlsA4ikxASBaH4AEbQZHDWyREHnRJXdIk%20bvajdAD0euQAAMNYijchgASjXlpXKFUaAHTIABywCQAEJPqQOSAuTz%20YLuGKNoCuVBQPxurb5VBFTZyKMJZsitqtg77MZwwJhJJOqtfAEk6IU29nTKY8XxLmTqr4uqnprWdrpZV9YaTQ2zRaCXwft1ZWlkH5aH75ca8mGI7hHcgABJsADudjY3mAWItYCcaiAA)

Comment: `type C<TChildProps, TStateValue = never> =
  TStateValue extends never? A<TStateValue> : B<TStateValue, TChildProps>` is safer because `TChildProps` and `TStateValue` may have the same type use case

Comment: @AcidCoder that's a very good point.  I was not envisioning a case where we would want converters from a string to a different string.  But now that I think about more that is a definite possibility.

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this is to declare only one interface type and set two properties optional and return the type never. One catch here is that two keys always will be optional i.e toValue and fromValue

```
interface IP<T> {
  value: T
  onChange: (value: T) => void
}

interface IProps<TStateValue, TInputValue> {
  toValue?: (value: TStateValue) => TInputValue | never
  fromValue?: (value: TInputValue) => TStateValue | never
  children: (inputProps: IP<TInputValue>) => null
}

const propsWithoutToValue: IProps<number, string> = {
  children: (inputProps) => null
}
const propsWithToValue: IProps<number, string> = {
  toValue: (value) => value.toString(),
  fromValue: (value) => Number(value),
  children: (inputProps) => null
}
```

Comment: In this case `inputProps` in the `propsWithoutToValue` is `IP<string>`, but must be `IP<number>` because the `toValue` function is not specified.

Comment: then in this case, you can switch the data types passed in IProps. ```IProps<string, number>```

Comment: I have more complex example where this types detected automatically depends on another props. I can't change the order of this types.

Comment: I created a repo where I describe this example https://github.com/oxilor/form-types